# Updated sitemap not read automatically by Google

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap

Google is not reading my sitemap of my wordpress site automatically. The 'last date read' remains the same as the submitted date. I had updated the contents of my site a couple of weeks ago, and the contents of sitemap were also updated automatically. But the updated sitemap was not read automatically by Google thereafter. I waited for a week but it remained the same. Finally, I was forced to resubmit the sitemap and google now discovered by new URLS immediately.

Is this normal? Does google take weeks to read sitemaps? Or is this some problem from my website side?

Comment: Why do you need Google to read the sitemap?   XML sitemaps don't help get your pages indexed or ranked.   It is usually better to link to your pages on your site and let Googlebot find them from there.   WordPress usually does that automatically for you.   See [Myth: An XML sitemap is needed for SEO; it helps rankings](https://blog.ostermiller.org/xml-sitemap-rankings/)

Comment: I am using wordpress.org., not wordpress.com. So my website was not indexed by Google in the initial weeks until I submit my XML sitemap in the Google webmaster tool.

Comment: I was assuming that you were using the WordPress CMS from wordpress.org rather than hosting on wordpress.com.     Sitemaps have very little influence over with SEO and Googlebot can crawl WordPress sites just fine without one.  It doesn't hurt to have a sitemap, but it won't control whether your site is indexed or not.

Comment: So you mean now that my website is indexed already, I just have to make sure that I have to put links to my new posts/pages in my already indexed pages/posts? So that Google bots will find them?

Comment: I don't know if your website is already indexed, but linking to every page is the best way to give each page the best shot of being indexed and ranking well.

Comment: Okay thanks :) ...